# Is it semantically correct to include two <nav> elements on a page for primary AND secondary navigation?

Tags: html

My page has two sections where there are a "list of links". The first is the primary i.e.

```
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="/">Homepage</a></li>
        <li><a href="/testimonies.html">Testimonies</a></li>
        <li><a href="/contact-us.html">Contact Us</a></li>
        ...
    </ul>
</nav>
```

This is a no brainer, ‘nav‘ is suitable here.

The second list of links is a list of categories such as:

```
Rock Music
Dubstep Music
Dance Music
Hip Hop Music
Electro Music
Classical Music
...
```

Is it semantically correct to use a  element for the secondary list?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Depending on the documentation...seems legit. There is an example with two `nav` elements for primary and secondary navigation as well.

http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/sections.html#the-nav-element

Comment: Ah I was reading this http://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/nav that's where the confusion was from. "w3 nav element" in Google didn't seem to bring up the actual documentation.